# RBP register value in windbg windows stack

Tags: c, windows, assembly, windbg, stack-unwinding

If i have code flow like main()--> a()--> b()-->c(), if I break in debugger(windbg) at c() and dump register values of all frames in debugger as ".frame /r frame_number"......do i see correct value for RBP every frame ? From documentation, i see RBP is a non volatile register and is saved during function call....does this mean we will get correct RBP value only while unwinding ?.....if I stop in debugger and dump in above fashion, will I not get correct value...if so how will debugger show the variable values for all frames if we click on that frame

Comment: It depends how you compiled.  *is a non volatile register*: yes.  *is saved during function call*: no.  The easiest way to keep the caller's value is not to touch RBP at all.  Using it as a legacy frame pointer is optional, and goes beyond what's required for a call-preserved register.  Debug builds do normally default to `gcc -fno-omit-frame-pointer` or equivalent, though.

Comment: debug builds are less peformant.....i think use of flag -fno-omit-frame-pointer will cause performance issues......is there any other way to not touch RBP ?.....Assume we didn't use above flag, can we assume output of  .frame /r command will have correct value of RBP ?

Comment: The equivalent of -fno-omit-frame-pointer for windows /Oy[-] is valid only for ia32.....i guess there is no such flag for win64

Comment: You mean for MSVC?  gcc and clang both work fine on Windows.

Answer (score 0):

you may also need to override local context with /c else baseptr of frame 0 will be displayed for all frames if you are going  to use the it for some purpose

```
:\>ls -lg & cat stackbase.cpp
total 4
-rw-rw-rw-  1 0 354 2020-11-24 19:46 stackbase.cpp


#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int c (int c) {
    return c+9;     //16
}
int b (int b) {
    return b+c(7);  //21
}
int a (int a) {
    return a+b(5);  //argv[1]==0=>21
}
int main ( int argc , char* argv[] ) {
    int ans = 0;
    if(argc == 2) {
        ans = a(atoi(argv[1]));
    }
    printf("%d\n", ans);
    return ans;
}


:\>cl /Zi /W4 /analyze /Od /EHsc /nologo stackbase.cpp /link /release
stackbase.cpp

:\>stackbase.exe  1316
1337
```

under windbg broken on c() with callstack;

```
:\>cdb -c "bp stackbase!c \"kc\";g" stackbase.exe 1316

Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.18362.1 X86

CommandLine: stackbase.exe 1316

0:000> cdb: Reading initial command 'bp stackbase!c "kc";g'

stackbase!c
stackbase!b
stackbase!a
stackbase!main
stackbase!invoke_main
stackbase!__scrt_common_main_seh
kernel32!BaseThreadInitThunk
ntdll!__RtlUserThreadStart
ntdll!_RtlUserThreadStart

eax=00000524 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000524 edx=00000000 esi=011ea760 edi=003c9128
eip=011a1000 esp=0026f958 ebp=0026f960 iopl=0         nv up ei pl nz na pe nc
cs=001b  ss=0023  ds=0023  es=0023  fs=003b  gs=0000             efl=00000206
stackbase!c:
011a1000 55              push    ebp
0:000>
```

you can check the difference with these two commands

```
0:000> !for_each_frame ".frame /r @$frame; r ebp"
0:000> !for_each_frame ".frame /r /c @$frame; r ebp"
```

here is the result for just /r which will always print the last set baseptr
while ebp is differnet in all other frames in this 32bit demo

```
0:000> !for_each_frame ".frame /r @$frame; r ebp"
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
00 0026f954 011a101a stackbase!c
00 0026f954 011a101a stackbase!c
eax=00000524 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000524 edx=00000000 esi=011ea760 edi=003c9128
eip=011a1000 esp=0026f958 ebp=0026f954 
stackbase!c:
011a1000 55              push    ebp
ebp=0026f960
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
01 0026f960 011a103a stackbase!b+0xa
01 0026f960 011a103a stackbase!b+0xa
eax=00000524 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000524 edx=00000000 esi=011ea760 edi=003c9128
eip=011a101a esp=0026f95c ebp=0026f960
stackbase!b+0xa:
011a101a 83c404          add     esp,4
ebp=0026f960
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
02 0026f96c 011a107e stackbase!a+0xa
02 0026f96c 011a107e stackbase!a+0xa
eax=00000524 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000524 edx=00000000 esi=011ea760 edi=003c9128
eip=011a103a esp=0026f968 ebp=0026f96c
stackbase!a+0xa:
011a103a 83c404          add     esp,4
ebp=0026f960
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
03 0026f97c 011a12e3 stackbase!main+0x2e
03 0026f97c 011a12e3 stackbase!main+0x2e
eax=00000524 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000524 edx=00000000 esi=011ea760 edi=003c9128
eip=011a107e esp=0026f974 ebp=0026f97c
stackbase!main+0x2e:
011a107e 83c404          add     esp,4
ebp=0026f960
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _
04 (Inline) -------- stackbase!invoke_main+0x1c
04 (Inline) -------- stackbase!invoke_main+0x1c
eax=00000524 ebx=7ffd7000 ecx=00000524 edx=00000000 esi=011ea760 edi=003c9128
eip=011a12e3 esp=0026f984 ebp=0026f9c4
```

Comment: "you may also need to override local context with /c else baseptr of frame 0 will be displayed for all frames" --- can you elaborate this point(override local context) a bit more (or) point me to any documentation......i am passing /c but still i see same RBP for multiple frames......this behavior is seen in my original code....if i try in a standalone, i am getting all RBP different for each frame

Comment: [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-hardware/drivers/debugger/-frame--set-local-context-)

Comment: i see repetition of same rbp thrice as shown below....also i see the same output with .frame /r /c and .frame /r......
 rbp=000000f088d264d0. 
 rbp=000000f088d266f0 --> 1. 
 rbp=000000f088d266f0 -->1. 
 rbp=000000f088d27940. 
 rbp=000000f088d279d0. 
 rbp=000000f088d28e10. 
 rbp=000000f088d29c30. 
 rbp=000000f088d2cfb0. 
 rbp=000000f088d2dad0. 
 rbp=000000f088d2eee0. 
 rbp=000000f088d2f220. 
 rbp=000000f088d2f460 --> 2. 
 rbp=000000f088d2f460 --> 2. 
 rbp=000000f088d2f990 --> 3. 
 rbp=000000f088d2f990 -->3. 
 rbp=0000000000000000. 
 rbp=0000000000000000.